# How to format f.submit with css, glyphicons, and symbol?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, submit

How can we make this: `<%= f.submit :conceal %>` work with `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">`, the word `Private`, and `class: "btn"`.

Here were some attempts:

```
#This didn't make :conceal work
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <% :conceal %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Private
<% end %>

#This stopped :conceal from working too
<%= f.submit "Private", class: "btn" do %>
  <% :conceal %>
<% end %>

#This ignored the 2nd line despite, do
<%= f.submit :conceal, class: "btn" do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Private
<% end %>
```

In **controller**:

```
if (params[:commit] == 'conceal')
  @valuation.conceal = true
end
```

Comment: Don't put "do"...in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't achieve button's appearance with icon when using `input[type=submit]`.

You have to go with `button`. Please, consider following:

```
<%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn", name: "commit", value: "conceal") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Private
<% end %>
```

Which generates HTML similar to:

```
<button name="commit" type="submit" class="btn" value="conceal">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Private
</button>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're amazing! I knew it had to be a simple solution. Sometimes the toughest problems are :) I'll award the bounty to you when I'm able to. Hope all is well, Pawel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <%= f.submit :conceal, class: 'btn', autofocus: true %>
  raw('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">"Private"</span>')
  <% end %>
```

Comment: This gave a syntax error: `unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'` The message was a lot longer than this. I can't pinpoint how to fix it

Comment: Doesn't work either :/ I tried using button_tag instead to no avail: `<%= button_tag(type: :conceal, class: "btn") do %> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Private <% end %>`

Comment: Sorry why's that? I used it here, which works: `<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn", id: "gold")  do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Public
  <% end %>`

Comment: Your line is giving: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: <%= form_for @example do |f| %>
  ...
    <% end %>

Comment: do is used in the beginning

Comment: If you take `do` out then `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">"Private"</span>` is left hanging. The `<% end %>` as part of the form is not included in this question because I had also left out `<%= simple_form_for(@valuation) do |f| %>`

Comment: why you are leaving them out ...try by including it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.button :submit, name: "conceal", value: "1" do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">private</i>
<% end %>
```

In your controller you will get params[:conceal] with the value "1".

Comment: I need `:conceal` in there.

Comment: I updated my answer, hope this will helpful for you. @AnthonyGalli.com

Comment: No still says false. And Shows "1" on the button instead of "+ Private"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set the span on locale file should work, something like:

```
en:
   helpers:
       submit:
           your_model_name:
               create: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Private"
```